# Easier way to create vector from condition

Tags: r

I want to create multiple vectors from one existing vector (in a dataset) based on two conditions

Right now I have a dataset (`DCE_unformat`) that contains a vector "Packaging" that has 4 levels: "container", "pallet", "container & pallet" or "other". Now I want to create 3 vectors based on the vector `DCE_unformat$Packaging` based on 2 conditions:
1st vector: `== 1` if value of `DCE_unformat$Packaging == "container"`, `== -1` if value of packaging `== "other"`, `0` otherwise
Same for the 2nd and 3rd vector but than with the 2 other packaging types.

Right now I wrote a for loop with a nested if statement for each condition that will do the job, but for future tasks I was wondering if this could be done more convenient.

```
DCE_unformat <- read.csv2(paste(getwd(),"/Data/data.csv",sep=""), header = TRUE)

DCE_unformat$P1 <- rep(0,4000)
DCE_unformat$P2 <- rep(0,4000)
DCE_unformat$P3 <- rep(0,4000)

for (i in 1:4000) {
    if(DCE_unformat$Packaging[i] == "pallet") {
    DCE_unformat$P1[i] <- 1
  } else if (DCE_unformat$Packaging[i] == "container") {
    DCE_unformat$P2[i] <- 1
  } else if (DCE_unformat$Packaging[i] == "container en pallet") {
    DCE_unformat$P3[i] <- 1
  } else if (DCE_unformat$Packaging[i] == "other") {
    DCE_unformat$P1[i] <- -1
    DCE_unformat$P2[i] <- -1
    DCE_unformat$P3[i] <- -1
  }
}
```

Comment: to me it looks like you would want to create a dummie-variable out of the factor Packaging. There is a package called fastDummies which allowes to create dummys easy: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastDummies/fastDummies.pdf, Example: https://rdrr.io/cran/fastDummies/man/dummy_cols.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a vectorized way.

```
DCE_unformat$P1 <- as.integer(DCE_unformat$Packaging == "pallet")
DCE_unformat$P2 <- as.integer(DCE_unformat$Packaging == "container")
DCE_unformat$P3 <- as.integer(DCE_unformat$Packaging == "container en pallet")
i <- DCE_unformat$Packaging == "other"
DCE_unformat$P1[i] <- -1
DCE_unformat$P2[i] <- -1
DCE_unformat$P3[i] <- -1
```